# Styling wordpress custom category templates

Tags: php, css, wordpress, styles, categories

I have a created a custom category template for parent categories which displays only the child categories rather than all the posts contained (category-slug.php). I found a code which calls all the categories but can't work out how to style the content individually. How can I apply styles to the contents when called up?

I've also installed the plugin 'Category images' as I'd like to style the contents and implement images for each category on the template.

Here is the code I am currently using...

```
    <?php wp_list_categories('&title_li=&show_count=1&child_of='.$current_cat); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the output of your categories list, just look in your browser and check your source code. Then just match the elements which you want to style.

Also if you are using google chrome, you can right-click on an element and choose an option called Inspect Element. Should be easier that way to match elements..